# Images outside JAR file?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I'm really confused... So my files structure is something like this

```
 /PCBuilder
   -PCBuilder.jar <= The main program
   /PCBuilder/Images
      /accessories/*.png files here
      /gui/*.png files here
      /parts/*.png files here
      /prebuild/*.png files here
```

My code

```
 private void okMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
    ok.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/PCBuilder/images/gui/Okay_glow.png")));
}                               

private void okMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
    ok.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/PCBuilder/images/gui/Okay_red.png")));
}
```

When I run it on Netbeans, it works fine... But when I try to compile it and run the JAR file, it shows this error...

```
 D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PCBuilder_GUIHACKED\dist>java -jar PCBuilder_GUIHACKED.jar
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at PCBuilder.welcomescreen.okMouseEntered(welcomescreen.java:87)
 at PCBuilder.welcomescreen.access$100(welcomescreen.java:12)
 at PCBuilder.welcomescreen$1.mouseEntered(welcomescreen.java:45)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: *"Any ideas how to fix this?"* Ensure the images are **inside** the Jar file (or at the very least, on the run-time class-path of the app..)..

Comment: "or at the very least, on the run-time class-path of the app.." how ?

Comment: BTW - what is the type of `ok`?  A `JButton` has inbuilt functionality to change icons on mouse over..

Comment: "BTW - what is the type of ok? " jLabel, acting as a button :)

Comment: *"or at the very least, on the run-time class-path of the app.." how ?"*  (bangs head against desk)  I *knew* I should not have mentioned that!  These images seem to be very much an 'application resource'.  How are you intending to distribute them, if not in the executable Jar?

Comment: *" jLabel, acting as a button"*  Aaaaaargh!  Use a (bloody) button.  The button can be undecorated if need be (i.e. visually indistinguishable from a label).

Comment: It's outside the JAR ... So basically, the JAR file should grab images on the /images folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is in parent directory of the executable jar file, so it's better to get parent path and then read images from the directory:

As a solution:

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().
                        getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
String path = f.getParent() + "/images/print.png";
lbl1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
```

1.Get the jar file path:

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().
                        getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

2.Get the absolute path of image(e.g. {jar_file_parent_directory}/images/print.png):

```
String path = f.getParent() + "/images/print.png";
```

3.Set icon for component(e.g. JLabel lbl1)

```
lbl1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
```